# Структура классов в проекте java

Tags: java, ооп, проектирование

В Desktop Swing приложении есть класс `Item` в пакете Data, класс `ItemFrame` (графическое заполнение и редактирование класса `Item`) в пакете GUI и класс `NetWorker` в пакете NetDB для работы с DB и сетью. Имена классов и пакетов - условные.

По логике программы, при создании (и редактировании) экземпляра класса `Item` вызывается графический интерфейс `ItemFrame` в который заносятся данные, при нажатии кнопки "Сохранить" создается объект `Item`, который должен быть записан в DB и, при определенных условиях, должны вызываться методы для его передачи по сети и записи в XML.

Получается, что при нажатии кнопки вызывается конструктор `Item` из другого пакета, и методы по работе с DB и сетью из третьего. Выглядит немного запутанно.
Как в таком случае правильно организовать структуру, в каком классе какие методы лучше реализовать?

Интересует именно правильное решение с точки зрения ООП.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вы на верном пути. Разделение пакетов по обязанностям -- это правильно. Тот факт, что при этом будет какое-то место, которые вызывает код из нескольких пакетов -- неизбежен.

Возможно вам стоит придерживаться классической трехслойной архитектуры UI->BLL->DAL (стрелками обозначено направление взаимодействия). Первый и последний слои у вас уже есть, осталось ввести слой бизнес-логики. UI будет передавать ему данные (или уже заполненный `Item`), BLL будет создавать/брать переданный `Item` и образаться к NetDB для сохранения.

Comment: То есть, сейчас ситуация нормальная, когда всё, что связано с GUI, включая обработчики событий интерфейса, в одном пакете, всё, что связано с DB  и сетью в другом, а бизнес логики, как таковой нет, в BLL только один класс?

Comment: @Tariel да. Само разделение по пакета -- это абсолютно правильно! Потому что каждый пакет/слой имеет строго очерченный круг обязанностей. Тот факт, что BLL у вас пока маленький -- это временная ситуация. Приложение будет расширяться, BLL (и другие слои) будут расти. Например, вам возможно понадобится валидация введенных в UI данных. Делать ее нужно именно на стороне BLL.